# Validate with crudRepository Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Java Spring and I stumbled across a problem:
Let's say I have a simple database that stores events that have a DateFrom and a DateUntil and you can access it including a simple Crud Repository. When a form containing a new Event is submitted, I want to first validate that there is no intersection with existing Events from the repository. I couldn't make it work with a ConstraintValidator, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: do you have a schema.sql or are you generating your tables based on your object model?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can use autowiring in the constraint validator and then retrieve the information from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validation by using the hibernate-validator framework. The following link points to the documentation of hibernate-validator:

- [Hibernate-validator documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints)

The custom validation can be applied to the entity object.